# What do the concepts "worlds" "souls" and "Divinity" mean in Chassidus?

Tags: torah-study, mitzvah, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, baal-shem-tov

[image]BH

What do the concepts "worlds" "souls" and "Divinity" mean in Chassidus? I have seen these in different places, together main question is from this book in the picture.

Is this from Chabad Chassidus or another Chassidus?

Source Of Picture:Hebrew Letter Rav Yitzchak Ginsburg

Comment: A textual source (where you saw it) or the original Hebrew would be helpful.

Comment: While “I have seen these in different places, together.” Is legitimate, with a question like this, a link to something we could look up would help a lot. Especially because Chassidus wasn’t delivered in English, so the translation is an interpretation of a concept.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's this: https://inner.org/parshah/genesis/vayeitzei/E68-0302.php. It is explained pretty thoroughly in this book: https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Alef_beit.html?id=5YVLC35h3B8C&redir_esc=y. What's your native language?

Comment: Those are basic terms found in all of Judaism.

Comment: In Chassidus: World: Sphere of existence. Soul: Capacity of man to achieve spiritual awareness. Divinity: Capacity of man to live in God's world in this world through fine-tuning the sensitivity of his *neshama* to both worlds.